# Django, ManyToMany field

Tags: django

I have two models in my blog app:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

class Post(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                            blank=True)
```

In views i have:

tags = Tag.objects.all()

And

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                         status="published",
                         publish__year=year,
                         publish__month=month,
                         publish__day=day,
                         slug=post)
```

So my question is - how can i filter tags by post ? I mean that i want to show only tags what i add to my post. I tried to do than in template , but something dosen't work :

```
 {% for tag in tags %}
 {% if tag in post %}
   <div> 
     {{ tag.tag_name }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("draft", "Draft"),
        ("published", "Published"),
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date="publish")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name="blog_posts",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                            blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default="draft")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/%Y/%m/%d",
                              blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-publish",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail",
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime("%m"),
                             self.publish.strftime("%d"),
                             self.slug])
```

The answer is:

```
{% for tag in post.tag.all %}
    <div class="fa fa-plus-square">
     <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.id %}">{{ tag.tag_name }}</a>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you got the ManyToMany concept wrong? If you put a ManyToMany in `post` you can just call to `post.tag` and it will show every tag that is created and usable in that post. I don't get why you are trying to set the `Tag` object as well in your html? A filter should be doable with `Post.objects.filter(tag=tags)` if I am correct.

Comment: In post_detail.html i want to show all information about chosen post. How can i show list of tags for this post?

Comment: You need to filter on the ID of that post and then print that information on the detail page

Comment: I want to do like this : post_tags = post.tag() , but i don't know how to wright it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a `ManyToManyField` in the `Post` class, it would be clearer if that field was called `tags` rather than `tag`, since it is referring to more than one thing.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="blog_tag",
                            blank=True)
```

So once you have looked up a post with:

```py
post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                         status="published",
                         publish__year=year,
                         publish__month=month,
                         publish__day=day,
                         slug=post)
```

You pass it to the template with:

```py
return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

And then in the `post_detail.html` you can render the tags associated with the post:

```
{% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    <div> 
        {{ tag.tag_name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

No need to explicitly filter the tags as the `ManyToManyField` handles that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
 {%for tag in tags %}
    {% if tag.id == post.tag.id%}
       <div> 
         {{ tag.tag_name }}
       </div>
    {%endif%}
 {%endfor%}
```

Comment: May be problems because of the ManyToManyField ?

Comment: What does "post" return ?

Comment: Don't understand question. How can i see it? My model is :

Comment: I added my post model